# How to pass Authentication for Thymeleasf template during unit test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-test

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.8.RELEASE. I have a controller which has the following method construct

```
@PostMapping(value = "/profile/change-password", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> changePasswordSubmit(Authentication authentication, @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
```

And My unit test which looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = ChangePasswordController.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@Import({ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class, SpringSecurityContextUtils.class})
@WithMockUser(username = "test", password = "password")
public class ChangePasswordControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;
    @MockBean
    SpringUserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    @Autowired
    ChangePasswordController controller;

    @MockBean
    Authentication authentication;

    @Test
    public void addNewEntrySubmit() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        formData.put("password1", Collections.singletonList("password"));
        formData.put("password2", Collections.singletonList("password"));

        webTestClient.post().uri("/profile/change-password").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData)).exchange().expectStatus().isSeeOther().expectHeader().valueEquals(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "/page/1");

//        verify(userDetailsRepository).updatePassword(captor.capture(), captor.capture());
        doNothing().when(userDetailsRepository).updatePassword(any(), any());
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run the test the Authentication value on the controller is null. I have tried to add the security context but am having issues with getting it right. How do I fix this

Update:
Link to example repository: https://github.com/dmbeer/thymeleaf-spring-security-test

Comment: Seems like something else might be going on. When I copy your test and controller into my application, the test completes fine. I had to tweak it to remove some of your internals and to add a csrf token, but you can see my example app at https://github.com/jzheaux/so-55365324.

Comment: Hi @jzheaux, thanks for this, it seems that if I change your version of Spring Boot to 2.0.8.RELEASE same as mine it fails with same error. I have updated question with spring boot version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Spring Boot 5.1.x, you need to add the Spring Security filter configuration manually:

```
WebTestClient webTestClient = WebTestClient
        .bindToController(new ChangedPasswordController())
        .webFilter(new SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter())
        .apply(springSecurity())
        .configureClient()
        .build();
```

In 5.1.x, `@WebFluxTest` adds these calls automatically, so you don't have to.

You can see an example of it in [the Spring Security repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/test/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/test/web/reactive/server/SecurityMockServerConfigurersAnnotatedTests.java#L45).

Comment: Hi @jzheaux, thanks for this. However having tried both this approach and the one in the documentation. I am still having issues so much so that now both tests are failing the submit with same error as before and the getthepage with failed to find view. I have updated the question with link to project that reproduces the issue, thanks

Comment: I've downloaded your code, and, happily, the `Authentication` is resolved correctly. If you debug into the controller method, you'll see that the `Authentication` instance is indeed there. The reason for the NPE the test throws is because there is no behavior mocked on userDetailsRepository.

Comment: Hi After lots of trial and error I have everything working. Had o change it slightly to bindToApplicationContext, so that it would find the other pages. Final solution below.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

So after help from @jzheaux and the relevant documentation, and guide for webflux https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.11.RELEASE/reference/html/test-webflux.html

My Unit Test looks like the following:

````
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @Import({ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
    @WebFluxTest(controllers = ChangePasswordController.class)
    @WithMockUser(username = "test", authorities = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    @ContextConfiguration 
    public class ChangePasswordControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @MockBean
    SpringUserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<String> captor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .webFilter(new SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter())
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getChangePasswordPageTest() {
        EntityExchangeResult<String> result = webTestClient
                .mutateWith(csrf())
                .get().uri("/profile/change-password")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(String.class).returnResult();

        assertThat(result.getResponseBody(), stringContainsInOrder(Arrays.asList("<title>Change Password</title>",
                "<input type=\"password\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"password1\" name=\"password1\">")));
    }

    @Test
    public void addNewEntrySubmit() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        formData.put("password1", Collections.singletonList("password"));
        formData.put("password2", Collections.singletonList("password"));

        given(userDetailsRepository.updatePassword(any(), any())).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        webTestClient.mutateWith(csrf()).post().uri("/profile/change-password").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData)).exchange().expectStatus().isSeeOther().expectHeader().valueEquals(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "/page/1");

        verify(userDetailsRepository).updatePassword(captor.capture(), captor.capture());
//        doNothing().when(userDetailsRepository).updatePassword(any(), any());
    }
}```
````